# audio.duration doesn't load automatically in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Working on a way to load the total amount of minutes an audio file has automatically when opening a page. It works fine in both Chrome and Safari but does not run in Safari unless i call the function by triggering with a button.

```
 (function($) {
  var aud = document.getElementById("track");

    var totdur = aud.duration;
    var min = Math.floor(totdur / 60);
    var sec = totdur - min * 60;
    var dur = min + ':' + Math.round(sec);

    $("#id").html(dur);

  })(jQuery);
```

I have tried to load it by using

```
  (function duration(){ //Name of function })()
```

and

```
  $(function() {
      // Code
  });
```

The output is often NaN:NaN. (Sometimes when i first open the page and after the reload it changes to the correct duration).

How can I make this work from the beginning and in all browsers?

**UPDATE:**
Solved it by using either `addEventListener`-tag for anything loaded before or

```
  window.onload = function () {

       var totdur = aud.duration;
       var min = Math.floor(totdur / 60);
       var sec = totdur - min * 60;
       var dur = min + ':' + Math.round(sec);

       $("#id").html(dur);

  };
```

Comment: Where is the `$(function()){}` called?

Comment: well is the audio file loaded?

Comment: @Paddy the function is called directly after `var aud = document.getElementById("track");`

Comment: @epascarello yes, it's loaded through an `<audio>` - tag in the HTML segment